# MYSQL use a case to subtract days from curdate()

Tags: mysql

I want to subtract either 30 days or 60 days from curdate() based on the listing fee using a case statement
If listing fee = 5 or 6, subtract 30 days
If listing fee = 7 or 8, subtract 60 days

I've tried this, but it does not seem to work

```
where `status`='C' and `close_date`>curdate() AND  `date_posted` < curdate() - 
CASE 
    WHEN listing_fee = 5 THEN INTERVAL 30 DAY
    WHEN listing_fee = 6 THEN INTERVAL 30 DAY
    WHEN listing_fee = 7 THEN INTERVAL 60 DAY
    WHEN listing_fee = 8 THEN INTERVAL 60 DAY

END
```

Comment: What if `listing_fee` has another value than 5, 6, 7 or 8?

Answer (score 0):

```
(CASE 
    WHEN listing_fee = 5 THEN  `date_posted` < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    WHEN listing_fee = 6 THEN  `date_posted` < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
    WHEN listing_fee = 7 THEN  `date_posted` < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
    WHEN listing_fee = 8 THEN  `date_posted` < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 60 DAY)
    ELSE 0/1 END # <- don't know what result
)
```